# Flutter align center and right on a wrap widget

Tags: flutter, alignment

I am using Wrap widget to align widgets on center and right, please see the below image what i am trying to achieve.

Using wrap widget instead of Row widget because widget get adjusted on available space when resizing the screen.

[image]

Below is the code tried to get the above result as shown in the image.

```
Wrap(
    alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
    runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
    spacing: 30.0,
    children: [
      Wrap(
        spacing: 20,
        children: const [
          Text("About Me"),
          Text("B"),
          Text("C"),
          Text("D"),
        ],
      ),
      Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Text("My Data"),
        ],
      ),
    ],
),
```

but widgets are not aligned properly, above code output as below.

[image]

Comment: any specific reason having nested wrap widget also are you trying to get same as   top image

Comment: yes, the reason behind is, I want to center align the first widget which is (about me, b, c, d) and right align the (my data) text widget. yes i am trying to get same as top image. I can achieve this using row but when I reduce the screen size row will break, but wrap widget will flow to next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        spacing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
        children: [
          Wrap(
            spacing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
            children: const [
              Text("About Me"),
              Text("B"),
              Text("C"),
              Text("D"),
            ],
          ),
          Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Text("My Data"),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the output

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the response, I tried this with row widget already but when screen size reduces it breaks, that's the reason i am using wrap widget.

Comment: Moreover it's not possible to use expanded or flexible with wrap widget, it throws "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" exception.

Comment: got your point and updated answer as expected.